# How to hide controls when it gets outside a canvas in WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, canvas

I'm working on a game using WP7 silverlight. Some controls are moving and at some point they get outside the canvas they where in.

I wonder why they are not hidden?

In windows forms when a control gets outside a panel for example, i.e:

```
control.left > panel.width
```

it disappears. Can this be possible in silverlight?

thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property.

The following will show a Button that will show outside of the Canvas because button width > canvas width:

```
<Canvas Width="200" Height="200">
    <Button>My button with a lot of text</Button>
</Canvas>
```

Now if I add the Clip property, what goes outside of the clip region gets hidden:

```
<Canvas Width="200" Height="200">
    <Canvas.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,200,200" />
    </Canvas.Clip>

    <Button>My button with a lot of text</Button>
</Canvas>
```